# Tornado URL regex patterns

Tags: python, regex, paypal, tornado

I have been getting a 405: Method Not Allowed when paypal uses the `return_url` back to my chosen HTML page.

I'm thinking is it because my **return_url** is: 'localhost:8000/ty' and below as:

```
app=tornado.web.Application(
    handlers=[(r'/', IndexHandler),(r'/ty', ThankYouHandler)], 
    db=db,
    template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
    static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
    #debug=True                        
)
```

However the url path received is: **127.0.0.1:8000/ty?token=EC-9YD54584BW887725V&PayerID=QQGSRNHDACTLJ**

So for my handlers to return to that page without a 405 Error, do I need to add regex to the `/ty` Handler to account for the url path.

How would I be able to handle regex in my handler then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `405: Method not allowed` error is returned when the HTTP verb used in the request isn't handled by Tornado. Meaning, for example, you received an HTTP POST request, but your handler only defines a `get` method. You need to determine what verb PayPal is using, and add a handler for that verb to your `RequestHandler`.

Comment: Hi....yes I have a post in my `Handler` and PayPal sends this back as a GET. I'll try to add a GET to the Handler as a `def get(self):` I did try this previously but I was not getting redirected to PayPal and instead landing on the the return_url which is now all blank.